# SiteFinity 7.1 custom content items and grouping

Tags: sitefinity

We have a list of faculty and units for a SiteFinity 7.1  site. We have these as custom content items in the site, because we are programming against them and building a few widgets around them.

However, we also have news about these faculty and units, and we'd like to use the existing news items in SiteFinity.

How do we easily tie faculty and units (custom content items) to news items (another content item baked into SiteFinity)? I wasn't sure if we create classifications that list faculty and units, and use these as the grouping mechanism? Or is there an easy way to tie two content items together? ﻿

Answer (score 0):

It kind of depends on how you're going to (or how you want to) display the data at the end. Here are a couple of different ways to achieve what you're after.

**You're planning on using the stock News widget to display the content.**

If this is true, using a custom taxonomy would be pretty easy in this case. Here's [a video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=uC4Gq6yZ4MA) that outlines this method.

**You're planning on displaying the news items in close proximity to one of the custom content types you've created.**

In this case, adding [a related data field](http://docs.sitefinity.com/content-relations-related-data) to the custom type would allow you [use related content items with widget templates](http://docs.sitefinity.com/for-developers-use-related-content-items-with-widget-templates).